# Webpack 5 Tailwind bundle too large

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, webpack-5, single-spa-angular

I have a stand-alone webpack application who's only job is to bundle s|css. The output javascript file acts as the main style for the rest of the micro-service architecture.

webpack config:

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa");

module.exports = webpackConfigEnv => {

  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: "stt",
    projectName: "styleguide",
    webpackConfigEnv
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
  });
};
```

I have imported a minified version of tailwind from my .scss (about 3MB in size) using npx `tailwindcss -o tailwind.min.css --minify`.

```
@import "tailwind.min.css";
@import "more styles..."
```

postcss.config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ],
};
```

After bundling, the ouput javascript is over 7MB in size.

How do I get the bundle size smaller?

**UPDATE**

Looking at the output js bundle, I can see there is a duplicate of all the styles/class names which seems to be the reason for the bloated file size.

Comment: Have you clear your cache or try to open it via incognito window (in chrome)?

Comment: The output webpack file itself is +7MB. It has nothing to do with the browser. This should not be an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: um, i'm appologize. 

For this problem, i recommend to evaluate your bundle with webpack bundle analyzer 

here was the url to see the step to configure: [link](https://blog.jakoblind.no/webpack-bundle-analyzer/)


thank you

Comment: I've done that. That did not help much. It just identified that tailwind was the largest css import. I managed to get it down to about 4MB using `devtool: 'nosources-source-map'` in the webpack config.

Comment: What version of Tailwind do you use? What's your config file content? Compiled CSS for Tailwind should not weight so much but it depends on configuration